# Bring Winforms control to front

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Are there any other methods of bringing a control to the front other than `control.BringToFront()`?

I have series of labels on a user control and when I try to bring one of them to front it is not working. I have even looped through all the controls and sent them all the back except for the one I am interested in and it doesn't change a thing.

Here is the method where a label is added to the user control

```
private void AddUserLabel()
{
    var field = new UserLabel();

    userContainer.Controls.Add(field);
    SendLabelsToBack(); // Send All labels to back

    userContainer.Controls[field.FieldName].BringToFront();
}
```

Here is the method that sends all of them to the back.

```
private void SendLabelsToBack()
{
    foreach (var label in userContainer.Controls);
        label.SendToBack();
}
```

Comment: Some example code would be nice. Are you sure the controls are in the same container control. Setting a control to front will only make it the front control in its container.

Comment: This post helped me solve the exact same problem.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yeah, there's another way.  The `Controls.SetChildIndex()` also changes Z-order.  The one with index 0 is the one on top.  Doesn't buy you anything though, `BringToFront()` uses this method.

Your `SendLabelsToBack()` method as given cannot work, it will also send the label to added to the back.  But your next statement fixes that again.

Okay, that doesn't work, which means the `BringToFront()` method doesn't get executed.  Look in the Output window for a "first chance exception" notification.  As written, your `SendLabelsToBack()` will cause an exception if the user control contains any control other than a UserLabel.  Also, set a breakpoint *after* the `BringToFront()` call and check the value of `userContainer.Controls[0].Name` when it breaks.

Comment: I don't really follow this the last portion because the form is only instantiated one time.

Comment: Just trying to come up with a reason that the label would not be visible.  Is it in fact visible but positioned wrong?  Or is it not visible at all?

Comment: It is visible behind another label.

Comment: After rechecking the name of the label I realized another label had accidentally been given the same name. So its BringToFont was being called instead of the one I wanted.  Should have caught this before asking the question...Thanks Hans.

Answer (score 6):

Controls' z-index is per-container.

If you call BringToFront on a control that is inside a container (such as a `Panel`), it will not bring the container to the front.
Therefore, the control will only go in front of other controls in that container.

To see what containers your controls are in, you can use the Document Outline pane in the View menu.

**EDIT**: Your `userContainer` control is probably behind a different control.

Comment: This is the "Gotcha"! Try moving the control you want to change visibility of out of the container, eg move a `Label` control out of a `GroupBox` container parent to be a child of the main `Form` container and it'll work.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `Invalidate()` after `BringToFront()`? BringToFront does not raise the Paint event

try this:

```
private void SendLabelsToBack()
{
    foreach (var label in userContainer.Controls)
    {
        label.SendToBack();
        label.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried and that didn't help either.  It appears like a couple labels have the same z-index and some don't.  From my understanding they should all have the same z-index if I set them manually.

Comment: Perfect answer. Worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to change your last line:

```
userContainer.Controls[field.FieldName].BringToFront();
```

to this:

```
userContainer.Controls[field.Name].BringToFront();
```

When you use a string as the indexer for the Controls collection, it goes by the `Name` property of the control (not the `FieldName` property).

Since you're just trying to bring the most recently-added control to the top, this would also work:

```
userContainer.Controls[userContainer.Controls.Count - 1].BringToFront();
```

Comment: No; otherwise, he would get an exception.

Comment: @Slaks: based on the usage in the question, it looks like `FieldName` would return the same value no matter which instance, like `FieldTop` and `FieldLeft` etc. So `FieldName` may just happen to be the same name as the first instance, so the call to BringToFront is always applied to the first control.

Comment: Why not type just `field.BringToFront()`? There's really no need to find it in the control collection when he already has a reference to it.

Comment: FieldName is property I created for the label(which is a user control as well)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience looks like windows puts all controls belonging to one graphic container(pane, group box...etc) in a software collection. The collection is ordered by child index which is a property of every control in that container. 
The trick is that children with the same index can and do exists. In this case windows will paint those children ordered relative to others but between them it will paint them in the reverse order they had been added to the container.

Long story short: for one container-you need to make sure controls have different indexes by changing ALL NOT just SOME of the indexes when you want to change the z-order. For example:

```
foreach (Control newControl in TopControl.Controls)
{
   TopControl.Controls.SetChildIndex(newControl,indexlogic(newControl));
}
```

where `indexLogic(newControl )` is your method of calculation of the index of particular control.